# Remove all duplicate characters from a string (STL)

Tags: c++, stl

Can anyone complete the following program?

Thanks.

```
void RemoveDuplicates (string& input)

{    
    string nonRepeatedChars (input);

    sort(nonRepeatedChars.begin(), nonRepeatedChars.end());
    //cout << nonRepeatedChars <<endl;
    string::iterator it = unique(nonRepeatedChars.begin(), nonRepeatedChars.end());
    //cout << nonRepeatedChars <<endl;
    nonRepeatedChars.erase(it, nonRepeatedChars.end());
    cout << "nonRepeatedChars = "<< nonRepeatedChars <<endl;

    for(string::iterator i = input.begin(); i != input.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << "*i = " << *i <<endl;
        size_t found = nonRepeatedChars.find(*i);
        cout << "found = "<< found <<endl;
        if (found != string::npos)
        {
             input.erase(i);
             cout << "input = " << input <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            nonRepeatedChars.erase(found, 1);
            cout << "nonRepeatedChars = "<< nonRepeatedChars <<endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Final Input = " << input <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  This question needs more details to avoid the impression of being "Please solve my problem." or "Please do my homework." You might also want to leasrn about formatting in order to improve readability.

Comment: The input is "bbccdddaaba". The output expected is "bcda"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution simple as always:

```
void RemoveDuplicates (std::string& input) {
  std::string::iterator it = std::unique(input.begin(), input.end());
  input.erase(it, input.end());
  std::cout << "New input = "<< input << std::endl;
}
```

Another solution to return a new string:

```
std::string RemoveDuplicates (const std::string& input) {
  std::string newT(input);
  std::string::iterator it = std::unique(newT.begin(), newT.end());
  newT.erase(it, newT.end());
  return newT;
}
```

If desired result is **hello** -> **helo** then the solution is :

```
std::string RemoveDuplicates (const std::string& input) {
  std::string newInput;
  const char * prev = nullptr;
  for (const auto & ch : input) {
    if (!prev || (*prev != ch)) {
      newInput.push_back(ch);
    }
    prev = &ch;
  }
  return newInput;
}
```

If you need to save order of chars and remove duplicates:

```
std::string RemoveDuplicates (const std::string& input) {
  std::string newInput;
  std::set<char> addedChars;
  for (const auto & ch : input) {
    if (addedChars.end() == addedChars.find(ch)) {
      newInput.push_back(ch);
      addedChars.insert(ch);
    }
  }
  return newInput;
}
```

Comment: What if OP doesn't want `input` to be sorted?

Comment: @Rakete1111: In this case he should add const std::string& to show his intentions and add to this function return value. Right now it is not pure function, but function with side effect

Comment: Yes, the function has side effects: removing the duplicates of `input`. But only that. It should not modify `input` in anyway. The order has to be the same. Your second solution has the same problem.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Check another version that I provide. If user provides not const reference it means user want modify this string otherwise it provides const reference

Comment: That's not my point. What the OP wants: `hello` => `helo`. What your functions do: `hello` => `ehlo`

Comment: @Rakete1111: Check the third solution =)

Comment: Good job, but there is a shorter solution: Remove the line with `std::sort` in your first solution, `std::unique` doesn't require the container to be sorted.

Comment: @Rakete1111: According to your explanation user wants the third solution

Comment: Yes, but just a call to `std::unique` and remove without the sorting also results in the correct solution.

Comment: The input is "bbccdddaaba".

The output expected is "bcda"

Comment: i beleive the for loop is not coorect

Comment: @DenisKotov I ran your solution. But they fail to satisfy the following case: The input is "bbccdddaaba". The output expected is "bcda"

Comment: @Mocka: But I have proper result str = bcdaba. Please, check again

Comment: @DenisKotov I appreciate your provided solutions. However, the expected solution is "bcda" in your case it is "bcdaba" the last "ba" should not be they are repeated

Comment: @Mocka: Take a look on fourth solution. It is what you want

Comment: @DenisKotov: The 4th solution works fine. This is what was required. Thanks mate....:)

Comment: @Mocka: In this case, please mark my answer as an answer on this question