# Deleting Duplicate chars from a string

Tags: c++, string, char, duplicates

Hello I'm kind of new to coding and I am writing a code that deletes any duplicate characters on a string. Let's say the input string was ABBA, then the output should be "empty" since all of the duplicates were deleted. Another example would be if the input string was KKCCD, then the output should be "D" as the code would remove the K and C duplicates. The problem with my code is that when I type KKCCD, it returns KCD and it doesnt delete the duplicates entirely. Also if I we're to type "AA" the result comes back as "A" instead of "Empty". Any help in fixing my code will be much apreciated. Thanks.

## include

```
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string deduplicate(string input){
int i;
int x;
int len= input.length();
string outputStr;
string strEmpty = "Empty";

if (input.length() == 1)
 {return input;}

for(i = 0; i<len;i++){
 for(x = i+1; x<len; x++){
    if(input[i] == input[x]){
        input.erase(x,1);

        x--;}

}
len = input.length();

}
return outputStr = input;

if (input.length() == 0)
{return strEmpty;}

return outputStr = input;
}


int main()
{
string input;
cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
cin >> input;
cout << deduplicate(input);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: one approach is to pick some symbol you know never gets used, like ~. Then instead of deleting, put a ~ in every occurrence of the duplicate.  In the end, copy all non tildes to your result string and return that.

Comment: Just keep an array of counters for each char, span the string, increase for each. Then span the string again with TWO pointers, copy from 2nd to 1st, always step 2nd, step 1st if non-dup. End when 2nd is end-of-str. Here you are: an O(n) algorithm instead of the slow ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your duplicate function to this

```
string deduplicate(string input){
int i;
int x;
int len= input.length();
string outputStr;
string strEmpty = "Empty";

if (input.length() == 1)
 {return input;}

for(i = 0; i<len;i++){
 for(x = i+1; x<input.length(); x++){  // This line
    if(input[i] == input[x]){
        input.erase(x,1); 
        input.erase(i,1);  // and this line
        x--;
    } 
 }
  len = input.length();
}
return outputStr = input;

if (input.length() == 0) 
{return strEmpty;}

return outputStr = input;
}
```

You did delete the duplicate character but not original, so the second erase statement does it.

Comment: This won't work since you are suggesting to delete the original character right after you find the very first duplicate. What if there is more more duplicate in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the duplicate you find, but you never delete the original character. The most efficient way to achieve your goal is to use STL algorithms. You might want to check out this link: [Remove all duplicate characters from a string (STL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704505/remove-all-duplicate-characters-from-a-string-stl)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I do not think if that is a good idea to delete characters from a string you are iterating. It would be much better and cleaner to construct your output instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string deduplicate(string input) {
    string outputStr;

    if (input.length() == 1) {
        return input;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
        // try to find character at the rest of the string
        if ( input.find( input[i], i+1 ) == string::npos ) {
             // try to find character in the front
            if ( ( i > 0 ) && ( input.rfind( input[i], i-1 ) == string::npos ) ) {
                outputStr += input[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return outputStr;
}


int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << deduplicate(input) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "brute force" implementation.

```
string deduplicate(string str)
{
  size_t l = str.length();    
  bool bFound = false;
  char character = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
    character = str[i];
    while (true)
    {
      size_t next = str.rfind(character);
      if (next != std::string::npos)
      {
        if (bFound || (!bFound && next != i))
        {
          str.erase(next, 1);
          bFound = true;
          l--;
        }
      }
      if (next == i)
      {
        if (bFound == true)
        {
          i--;
        }
        bFound = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```